# How to check for RuntimeError with Test/Unit

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing

In my program, I use raise "text" to prevent creating an object when parameters are wrong.

How can I check this in Test/Unit?

```
assert_ ? (MyObject.new(wrong,parameter))
```

How can I check that my object was not created?

Answer (score 2):

```
def test_illegal
  assert_raise( RuntimeError ) { MyObject.new('a') }
end
```